# what wrong with my system?

Tags: 15.10, kylin

my system is `Ubuntu kylin 15.10`, what is wrong with it? See the picture below:
[image][image]

Comment: Maybe your video card don't have enough memory, or you uses the wrong video driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a problem with video driver. What graphics card do you have? Do you use proprietary video driver? If not, try to install the proprietary one. If it doesn't help, try a Live session of another Ubuntu flavor, like Xubuntu, to see if the problem persists.